# ngx-bootstrap DatePicker, how to set display format for date

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

How do I set a custom format for the date the datepicker displays?

I'd like a long date format like 'November 4, 2017' or '4 Nov, 2017'. Something that's clear for multiple locals.

I've experimented with different properties of the options, but always end up with US short date format.

Answer (score 4):

To display date in 'November 4, 2017' format use the following config:

`this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, {
      dateInputFormat: 'LL',
      locale: 'en-gb'
 });`

And assign it to the date picker in html component:

```
<input ... bsDatepicker  [bsConfig]="bsConfig" />
```

Note there is [an existing issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2809) when patching form value. The link contains a possible workaround as well.

Answer (score 1):

To display date '4, Nov 2017' in this format.
use this config in html.

```
[bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY '}"
```

It works for me.

Comment: @Suraj Rao, May I know why have you edited this format? Is it essential to leave space in-between in date format

Comment: I didnt change your original dateInputFormat. I merely set it in a code block for readability. Check [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53846111/revisions). Feel free to make changes to your answer